# How can I send an HTML email from an Ajax callback?

Tags: 8, ajax, emails

I want to send an email to the user who forget username.

I created a functionality that handle with Ajax like send request to controller where I using a query to check whether user exist or not. if user exist I want to send email to used with his user name.

Is there any module that i can use to send email in this way

```php
public function ForgotUsername() {
  $mail = \Drupal::request()->query->get('mail');
  $database = \Drupal::database();
  $username = $database->query("SELECT name from users_field_data where mail='$mail'")->fetchField();
  
  if (!empty($username)) {
    $module = 'modulename';
    $key = 'forgotusernamerecovery';
    $to = 'example@example.com';
    $langcode = '';
    $params = ['username' => 'Abc'];
    drupal_mail($module, $key, $to, $langcode, $params = [], $reply = NULL, $send = TRUE);
    
    $message = "<div class='matched'>Successs</div>";
  }
  else {
    $message = "<div class='notmatched'>notmatched</div>";
  }
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('.selector', $message));
  return $response;
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for recommendations or suggestions on books, tools, modules, themes, distributions, tutorials, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend the [Easy Email module](https://dgo.to/easy_email). It combines with Swiftmailer and Mailsystem, allowing for creating and sending HTML emails, using templates you can build with a ckeditor right in the interface. Then you can send mails from your module using the standard Drupal mail service, and it will take care of turning it into an HTML email. The video on the top page of the module page is very informative and explains it all. It's by far the best HTML email solution I've found in Drupal over the years.

Answer (score 1):

[Swiftmailer](https://www.drupal.org/project/swiftmailer) in combination with[mail system](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailsystem) let you send html mail if correctly configured.
It's decently documented, the very short guide is:

1. go to: `admin/config/system/mailsystem`, set as formatter and sender swift mailer, use the front\whatever theme as theme for mail
2. (optional) set the formatter\sender for the specific module
3. go to `admin/config/swiftmailer/messages` check the configuration, the default should already work for html mails.

You could then override the opportune template twig to style your email. You can also definy a css file that swiftmailer will convert in inline-css. Check the readme for more details but in short you have to define inside the your_theme.libraries.yml file

```
swiftmailer:
  css:
    theme:
      css/my_theme.mail.css: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send emails using the MailManager class. If you are in the context of an injectable class I would strongly suggest to use dependency injection.

If now you can simply call the service like so:

```
\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail')->mail($module, $key, $to, $langcode, $params = array(), $reply = NULL, $send = TRUE);
```

In short just change `drupal_mail(...)` to `\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail')->mail(...)` and i believe that the above code will work as you intend it to.

**Edit:** Also make sure that in your .module file there is a hook like the one below.

**Edit 2:** Also remember to add subject and body in your params. And correct your function call, because as it is now you overwrite the $params to an empty array when you call the function.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail().
 */
function MYMODULE_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  $site_name = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('name');
  $site_mail = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('mail');

  switch ($key) {
    case 'my_module_key':
      $message['headers']['Reply-To'] = $site_mail;
      $message['headers']['From'] = $site_name . '< ' . $site_mail . ' >';
      $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
      $message['body'][] = $params['body'];
      break;
  }
```

This hook will manipulate the data to be used for the construction of the mail and is mandatory for the mail service to work.

**Caution:** the $key you use must be the same with the $key provided in the mail function call and the modulename.. well should be obvious :P

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I face two issue with this
(1) Error Type SMTP --- Error sending email (from abc@exmpale.com to xyz@example.com : Message body empty
(2) Error Type mail -- Mail : Error sending email (from abc@exmpale.com to xyz@example.com with reply-to not set).

Comment: When you try to use the mail service via a module you should have a hook_module in your .module file, which will manipulate some variables. I will edit my post to provide specifications.

Comment: Check the edited answer, and tell me if you are still getting errors.

Comment: TypeError: Argument 3 passed to t() must be of the type array, null given, called in

Comment: Check the updated version of the question.

Comment: This answer is not satisfactory because Drupal core doesn't support HTML email directly - you need additional code like a contributed module or your own code to be able to send HTML email. Custom code, like the code shown here, is not the best way to go because you have to implement too much / know too much to properly send HTML email on your own. For example, this answer says to use `$site_name` in the "From" address, which will fail if your site's name has non-ASCII characters. Best to let a contributed module do this the right way.